What did Cargus do in the later Lyonesse books?
In the first book of the Lyonesse trilogy, Aillas escapes from Ska captivity along with a group of friends, most of whom peel off along the way (either dying or settling down somewhere) except for the ultra-loyal Yane and Cargus, who accompany Aillas all the way to Troicinet to interrupt his cousin's coronation and kill him.
Later on, Yane is revealed to be the same person as Casmir's master spy, a triple agent passing false information to Casmir while pretending to be spying on Aillas. But is there any information about what Cargus gets up to after Aillas becomes king? Does he have any particularly important role in Troicinet, or simply live his own life?
